# Perl Spreadsheet::ParseExcel cannot parse and return undef

Tags: excel, perl, parsing, spreadsheet

Just installed `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` module, but got problem. See a few related question, but not exact the same.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                        

use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Data::Dumper;

my $bill = $ARGV[0] || die "Usage: $0 bill.xlsx\n";
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book2.xlsx');
print Dumper $workbook;

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheet() ) { }
```

When I run the perl script, I got following error:

```
Can't call method "worksheet" on an undefined value at read.bill.xlsx.pl line 15.
```

So I dumped `$workbook`, and got:

```
$VAR1 = undef;
```

and dumper parser shows some data. This means `$parser->parse` failed. Anybody know why? Thanks.

Comment: from the docs of [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel#DESCRIPTION). The module cannot read files in the Excel 2007 Open XML XLSX format. See the [Spreadsheet::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::XLSX) module instead.

Answer (score 2):

As [documentation suggest](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm#parse($filename,_$formatter)), you have to test if `parse()` returned `undef` and check error message,

```
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book2.xlsx') // die $parser->error();
```

Comment: Thanks for that and I got: No Excel data found. However, it confirms problem is $parser->parse.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $bill = $ARGV[0] || die "Usage: $0 bill.xlsx\n";
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('Book2.xls');

if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}

for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

After googling around, I found XLSX format requires Spreadsheet::XLSC instead of ParseExcel. Also the parse function take the filename then no need the step of $parser->parse.